# Launch command through popen on OpenShift

Tags: python, python-2.7, openshift, popen

When I launch this command through **popen**

```
try:
  os.popen("myCustomCmdHere")
except IOError:
  logging.error('Error on myCustomCmdHere')
```

**I don't have error but the command does not launch**

And when I launch myCustomCmdHere directly on Openshift console the command is right

```
rhc ssh -a myApp
cd app-root/repo/myApp
myCustomCmdHere
```

**What I need to add in my code to use os.popen in Openshift ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the '&' to start a separate process and send to background.  I use this for python  3.3 on Openshift.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['myCustomcmdHere &'])
```

Or this

```
os.system("myCustomcmdHere &")
```